# selectize widget of ggplotly highlight not always visible (depends on order of geoms?)

Tags: r, plotly, ggplotly

I want to do an interactive scatterplot where I can

- highlight individual points
- a tooltip shows me the id
- search for specific id with a selectize widget

[image]

I tried for some time with `plotly` and ended up with this code

```
library(tidyverse)
library(plotly)
set.seed(1)
dat <- tibble(id = LETTERS[1:10],
              trt = factor(rep(0:1, 5)),
              x = rnorm(10),
              y = x + rnorm(10, sd = 0.2)) %>% 
  highlight_key(~id)
dat %>% 
  {ggplot(., aes(x = x, y = y, group = id, color = trt)) +
      geom_point() +
      geom_hline(yintercept = 0, linetype = "dashed")} %>% 
  ggplotly(tooltip = c("id")) %>% 
  highlight(on = "plotly_hover", selectize = TRUE)
```

In a next step I wanted to plot the hline behind the points (i.e. reverse the order of the geoms)

However this led to problems shown below (widget missing or only working for one trt group

```
## no color, geom order reversed
## => selectize.js widget is completely missing
dat %>% 
  {ggplot(., aes(x = x, y = y, group = id)) +
      geom_hline(yintercept = 0, linetype = "dashed") +
      geom_point()} %>% 
  ggplotly(tooltip = c("id")) %>% 
  highlight(on = "plotly_hover", selectize = TRUE)

## color by trt, geom order reversed
## => selectize.js widget only works for data where trt = 0
dat %>% 
  {ggplot(., aes(x = x, y = y, group = id, color = trt)) +
      geom_hline(yintercept = 0, linetype = "dashed") +
      geom_point()} %>% 
  ggplotly(tooltip = c("id")) %>% 
  highlight(on = "plotly_hover", selectize = TRUE)
```

Can somebody explain this strange behavior? What if I would like to **reverse the order of geoms** i.e. hline ploted behind points?

Comment: This looks like a bug, maybe you can add an issue on GitHub?

Comment: Whatever the issue was, I can't replicate it now. Interesting...

Comment: @Kat for me the issue is still reproducible (R version 4.2.3, plotly version 4.10.1). Can you tell me what is not reproducible for you?

Comment: R version 4.2.1, Plotly: 4.10.2  I meant that changing the order did not change the output for me. However, I did just notice now (doublechecking) that the colors differ, but I can still search, still see the ID in the tooltips, and highlighting still does its thing. Is this code within something else for you? If you use it standalone, does it do the same thing?

Comment: @Kat Thanks. You're right! Updating to Plotly 4.10.2 solves to problem. The [release notes](https://github.com/plotly/plotly.R/releases/tag/v4.10.2) mention some improvements of the selectize.js implementation. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The release of Plotly 4.10.2 solved the problem. The [release notes](https://github.com/plotly/plotly.R/releases/tag/v4.10.2) mention some improvements of the selectize.js implementation.